# Export/Import databases faster than currently

Tags: mysql, bash, import

I have a database(MYSQL) that is exported in this way:

```
echo "Dump structure"
mysqldump -S /path/db.sock --user = $ {USER} --password = $ {PASSWORD} --single-transaction --no-data $ {DATABASE}> $ {DB_FILE}

echo "Dump content"
mysqldump -S /path/db.sock --user = $ {USER} --password = $ {PASSWORD} $ {DATABASE} --no-create-info $ {IGNORED_TABLES_STRING} >> $ {DB_FILE}
```

What it does is export the structure of some ignored tables and the contents of others. This is so to make the database occupy less space.

I'm not sure if there are more optimal ways to do this.

My question is this:

In "Dump Content" I would like to just take the last 1000 results to reduce its content, but the problem is that not all tables are related or contain the same field to filter them.

How can I filter the latest records if I can not do it for a single field?
Can I achieve an export / import of the database in a faster way?

Comment: MySQLdump does not support this (you can at most add a where filter, which neither supports "last x rows" nor unspecific column names). You can write a simple script for this, e.g. run mysqldump once for every table and add a `where`-condition that you calculate first, with some considerations about foreign keys and your knowledge about how to identify the last n rows of table x. Or google for a script or tool that does (parts of) this already, although adapting them to your needs is not necessarily easier than writing it on your own (and would belong, if at all, on dba.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't do that.

Long answer: you could do selects with a "LIMIT 1000" for example and write that into files. But whatever your reason behind this is, I strongly advice you to not do that. If you want to backup everything, do a full backup. If you want to keep the database fast, don't worry about that and learn how to use indexes. If you want to do that just to keep it well organized and get rid of data you don't need anymore, just keep them in the database because they don't do any harm. If you want to synchronize data with another database, set up a replication.